Sonarcloud and Sonarlint don't see NullPointerException java:S2259
I'm trying to use sonarcloud and sonarlint to catch more NPE exceptions.
To test this i created a simple service and added some clear problematic code but both sonarcloud and sonarlint don't see the problem with rule java:S2259 and i can't understand why!
Example:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "rest/template-java", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Log4j2
public class TemplateJavaController {

  @GetMapping
  public String templateJava() {
    log.debug("template-java");
    String test = null;
    boolean a = test.isEmpty();
    boolean b = returnNUll().isEmpty();
    return "template-java" + a + b;
  }

  @Nullable
  @CheckForNull
  private String returnNUll() {
    return null;
  }
}

IntelliJ actually detect the problem but Sonar not. Other kind of problem are detected so the analysis on the file works and i double checked that the rule java:S2259 is active
Thank you for your help!

You can enable "Analysis logs" and "Verbose output" in SonarLint, and check for any errors, perhaps you are missing some imports? I have this issue raised on your code snippet.

After some more testing i discovered that if @Log4j2 is used to autogenerate the "log" object and a method uses it then that method will never trigger S2259 if i remove from the method the "log" line or i manualy create the "log" object then the rules are triggered.
Still i don't know what is going on and why is behaving like that

If Sonar detects a NPE happening it's not moving forward with the analysis in that part of the tree.
In my case, it's working fine up to this line
boolean a = test.isEmpty();
But this line produces an NPE, so it won't continue analyzing, therefore this line issues are not detected
boolean b = returnNUll().isEmpty();
